# Pandas DataFrame to Dict with (Row, Column) tuple as keys and int value at those location as values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tuples

I am trying to make the following DataFrame

```
       A      B      C      D      E
A      0   7324  11765   6937  10424
B   7324      0  17791   3532   5902
C  11765  17791      0  17184  20608
D   6937   3532  17184      0   6550
E  10424   5902  20608   6550      0
```

to look something like this:

```
{
    ('A','A'): 0,
    ('A','B'): 7324,
    ('A','C'): 11765,
    .
    .
    .
    ('E','C'): 20608,
    ('E','D'): 6550,
    ('E','E'): 0,
}
```

Simply put, the output is a dictionary with 2-tuples as keys of rows and columns and values at those locations as dictionary's values. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then convert to dict:

```
df.stack().to_dict()
```

---

```
{('A', 'A'): 0,
('A', 'B'): 7324,
 ('A', 'C'): 11765,
 ('A', 'D'): 6937,
 ('A', 'E'): 10424,
 ('B', 'A'): 7324,
 ('B', 'B'): 0,
 ('B', 'C'): 17791,
 ('B', 'D'): 3532,
 ('B', 'E'): 5902,
 ('C', 'A'): 11765,
 ('C', 'B'): 17791,
 ('C', 'C'): 0,
 ('C', 'D'): 17184,
 ('C', 'E'): 20608,
 ('D', 'A'): 6937,
 ('D', 'B'): 3532,
 ('D', 'C'): 17184,
 ('D', 'D'): 0,
 ('D', 'E'): 6550,
 ('E', 'A'): 10424,
 ('E', 'B'): 5902,
 ('E', 'C'): 20608,
 ('E', 'D'): 6550,
 ('E', 'E'): 0}
```